# Call of overloaded constructor is ambiguous

Tags: c++, constructor, ambiguous

I am trying to implement an object-oriented binary tree, however, I get the error message of a call of an overloaded constructor being ambiguous. The problem is that I really do have the necessary constructor, yet C++ doesn't seem to recognize it.

My code: http://pastebin.com/PM9PDYAN

The error message:

```
56  36  In constructor 'Node::Node(const int&, Node*, Node*, const int&)':
56  36  [Error] call of overloaded 'Node(const int&, Node* const)' is ambiguous
17  3   [Note] Node::Node(const int&, Node*)
15  3   [Note] Node::Node(const int&, const int&, Node*) <near match>
15  3   [Note] no known conversion for argument 2 from 'Node* const' to 'const int&'
37  1   [Note] Node::Node(const int&, Node*, Node*, Node*)
```

Comment: Post the *relevant* code in the question, don't link to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two constructors with default arguments "overlap":

```
Node(const int&, Node* = nullptr, Node* = nullptr, Node* = nullptr);
```

And:

```
Node(const int&, Node* = nullptr);
```

Both of these could match a call with just an `int` or just an `int` and a `Node *`.

Looks like there are other overlapping constructors as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Node(const int&, Node* = nullptr, Node* = nullptr, Node* = nullptr);
Node(const int&);
Node(const int&, Node* = nullptr);
```

These three are ambigous calls as compiler won't be able to resolve the call if you call it by:-

```
Node node(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following constructors are ambiguous (among others). If the user say `Node node(5)`, the compilor does not know whether you meant `Node(const int& 5, Node* = nullptr);` or `Node(const int& 5)`.

```
Node(const int&, Node* = nullptr);
Node(const int&);
```